# Probability: Average times to use every element in a matrix

Tags: probability

Here is a matrix of 8*10 from 1 to 80.

Suppose we pick two distinct numbers to form an ordered pair.

Thus, we need to pick at least 40 pairs to have used every number.

*If one picks pairs randomly, what is the expected number of picks such that all of the numbers have been used?*

I think this can be figured out by calculating an expectation. 
Like the probability of 40 pairs to have every number used is: $$ P = \frac{80!}{\dbinom{80}{2}^{40}}$$
But I don't know how to calculate other probabilities.

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: "Average time" is too qualitaty, try something more quantitative like "How often pick pairs that with 90% probability ..."

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter I think what the OP says makes sense.  He is asking what is the expected number of trials such that you will have used every number.  If you do less than $40$ trials this probability is zero, if you do $40$ or more the probability should start small and increase (as you increase the number of trials)...this should give an expected value for $n$ as you sum $[n] = \sum_{n = 40}^{\infty}p(n)*n$.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. We have an $8\times 10$ matrix. It sounds as if the entries are all the integers from $1$ to $80$.  If so, what are the ordered pairs? You may want to look at the Coupon Collector's Problem (please see Wikipedia).

Comment: @Jared Yeah, the expectation is what I want.

Comment: @findslowly As André suggests, this sounds very similar to the [Coupon Collector's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem#Calculating_the_expectation).

Comment: @Jared OK, didn't look at this this way

Comment: One clarification: when I say $[n] = \sum_{n = 40}^\infty p(n)*n$, $p(n)$ must be the probability that it takes _exacly_ $n$ draws to use all numbers (this probability should become low as $n$ tends towards $\infty$ because it's unlikely that it will take that many draws to _not_ us all the numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some food for thought:
After the first pair, two numbers are used. From then on, each round takes us from knowing $k\ge2$ out of $n=80$ numbers to knowing either $k$, $k+1$, or $k+2$ numbers with probabilities
$$ \frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}\qquad\frac{2k(n-k)}{n(n-1)}\qquad\frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)}{n(n-1)}.$$
This can be treated with the theory of Markov processes. For example, the question after how many rounds does the probability to have seen all numbers exceed 50% is to ask for which power of the transtion matrix the corresponding entry exceeds $0.5$

---

Since $80$ is much large tan $2$, you may obtain a good approximation by looking up the *standard* coupon collector's problem, i.e. ask how many rounds does it take to collect all $80$ numbers with drawing *single* numbers and then divide the result by $2$ ...